# How does tensorflow deal with different number of samples in x and y

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I built a CNN model with Keras and tensorflow. When I trained this model, I made a mistake which the x and y fit into my model have different number of samples. But somehow the model started training as normal. So in such kind of situation, how did tensorflow deal with the excess samples in x or y? For example, if x has 100 samples and y has 110 samples, how does tensorflow deal with this 10 samples? Ignore them?

Comment: as you said it started working but did it throw  an error at some point ?

Comment: No error happened. I realized this mistake after training finished.

Comment: That depends on what kind of interface you are using to provide the data. It would help to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.